# SQL Query; Search List from List

Tags: mysql, sql, qsqlquery, qsqltablemodel

I am new at SQL, including performing queries. Everyday, our organization sends a list of employees that were terminated in a listed format. What I am looking to do is two things, search for the employee ID(s) in a `column` and if the employee is found, update a certain cell/field to `disable`.

For instance, if we get a list that has an employee ID's of `123456` and `234567`, I want to find those employee ID's in the `EMPID` field and then update their ACTIVE field from '1' to '0'.

What is the best possible way to do this?

EDIT, sorry for all the missing information as I am completely new to the forum and the coding world, and I'm, going to re-explain what I am trying to accomplish. Maybe a function? I changed the data below to be more consistent with what I am working with versus examples.

We get a text file everyday with a list of employee ID's that were terminated, that we need to deactivate in our application. I know this is still manual, but I think it is a good start for some automation.

1. On the `dbo.EnterpriseUser` table, we need the code to find the user by looking for the `IVRID` (Which is the employee's ID) and then update the `IsActive` field from `1` to `0`, and then update the `LastModDate` to the current date and time using the same format. Below is the example table I am working with, sorry if the formatting is not correct.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS EnterpriseUser (
   `EnterpriseUserID` INT,
   `FirstName` VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8,
   `LastName` VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf8,
   `IVRID` INT,
   `IsActive` INT,
   `LastModDate` DATETIME
   ```

   );
       INSERT INTO EnterpriseUser VALUES
       (6,'Robert','Andrews',2,1,'2018-07-11 13:01:54.670000');
2. The second table `dbo.Staff` must be properly updated as well for the application. My only problem is that to find the record to update, I have to use the `EnterpriseUserID` field from `dbo.EnterpriseUser` is now in the `StaffID` field on the `dbo.Staff` table.

On that row, the `LastModDate` must be changed to current date and the `IsActive` must change from `1` to `0`.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Staff (
    `StaffID` INT,
    `FirstName` VARCHAR(6) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `LastName` VARCHAR(7) CHARACTER SET utf8,
    `LastModDate` DATETIME,
    `IsActive` INT
);
INSERT INTO Staff VALUES
    (6,'Robert','Andrews','2018-07-11 13:01:54.670000',1);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!. Your question is difficult to answer because it doesn't include enough detail about your environment for us to help you. Please take a moment to read these two links, then consider editing your question if you're still looking for help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP asked for the `the best possible way to do this`, and I've never met a process where the best possible solution involved hand keying data.

Import your list into a holding table. Use that table to find and update the affected records. Archive the list, with a datestamp on each record indicating when they were processed.

This uses SQL Server syntax, but there's nothing fancy going on. Easy to translate to a different dialect.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.DailyTerminations (
  EnterpriseUserID INT
  );

BEGIN TRANSACTION --By using a transaction, both tables will update or neither will.  
                  --For MySQL, it's START TRANSACTION

  UPDATE eu
    SET IsActive = 0
  FROM 
    dbo.EnterpriseUser as eu
  JOIN
    dbo.DailyTerminations as dt
      ON dt.EnterpriseUserID = eu.EnterpriseUserID
  WHERE 
    eu.IsActive <> 0;

  UPDATE st
    SET IsActive = 0
  FROM 
    dbo.Staff as st
  JOIN 
    dbo.EnterpriseUser as eu
      ON
        eu.EnterpriseUserID = st.StaffID
  JOIN
    dbo.DailyTerminations as dt
      ON dt.EnterpriseUserID = eu.EnterpriseUserID
  WHERE 
    IsActive <> 0;

COMMIT TRANSACTION --For MySQL, it's just COMMIT

INSERT INTO dbo.TerminationArchive
(
 EnterpriseUserID,
 ProcessedDate
)
SELECT
  EnterpriseUserID,
  GETDATE()
FROM
  dbo.DailyTerminations;

TRUNCATE TABLE 
  dbo.DailyTerminations;
```

Comment: In this best solution where is DailyTerminations table in OP's system? If you are trying to find the best way how those IDs would be input without any "hand" in the first place do you think? Or why wouldn't you simply load into a temp table and create the unnecessary DailyTerminations table just to truncate it often? People always ask with "best" and it really depends on available sources, environment etc.

Comment: @CetinBasoz, you're absolutely right. We don't know enough about the question to give a best solution. I wish the OP would give us more to work with.

Comment: Hey Eric!! Can you please take a look at the edit I created in my post?  I tried to give better detail and information..

Comment: @Josh, I tweaked my answer based on the extra information you provided. It should handle both tables now.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using an update statement like:

```
update Employees
set Active = 0
where EmpId in (123456, 234567)
```

Comment: Which would be fine if the OP had a piece of paper with two EmpIDs on it, but I believe he's looking for help with join criteria.

Comment: @EricBrandt, join with what?

Comment: Exactly why I asked him for more details.

Comment: @EricBrandt, for someone who is not a "DBA" and simply wants to do stuff like this, writing this code in with IDs manually would be simple enough. If he is not a programmer, he doesn't need to learn how to effectively read the IDs from a text file and update the statuses. If he is, then knowing the language he uses would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an update statement if you're going to check them manually.

If you're inserting the employees in the table you can create a trigger to check these employees every time you make an insert.